# How to Configure Neural Network to Produce Multiple Binary Outputs in DL4J

Tags: java, neural-network, multiclass-classification, dl4j

I am learning [DL4J](https://deeplearning4j.org/quickref), and I would like to configure a network that can accept a tuple of double values, and produce a tuple of binary values, in which multiple of them may be set to 1, and others set to 0.  In the language of neural nets, would I cal this is multi-class one-hot encoding?

Example:

```
[3.5,  2.9, 15.0] -> [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[2.5, 12.5,  5.0] -> [1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[5.9, 71.3,  0.7] -> [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

etc.

I have tried this:

```
MultiLayerConfiguration multiLayerConfiguration = 
    new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
        .seed(System.nanoTime())
        .iterations(10000)
        .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT)
        .learningRate(0.1)
        .useDropConnect(false)
        .biasInit(0)
        .miniBatch(false)
        .updater(Updater.NESTEROVS)
        .list()
        .layer(0, new DenseLayer.Builder()
            .nIn(3)
            .nOut(8)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
            .activation(Activation.SIGMOID)
            .build())
        .layer(1, new OutputLayer.Builder()
            .nIn(8)
            .nOut(5)
            .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
            .activation(Activation.SOFTMAX)
            .lossFunction(LossFunctions.LossFunction.RECONSTRUCTION_CROSSENTROPY)
            .build())
        .pretrain(false)
        .backprop(true)
        .build();
```

But I seem to be getting fractional values in the output as if the network is trying to evenly distribute the activation.  How do I configure the network to make it give me multiple 1's and 0's as a classification?

For example, if the output was 3 dimensional, I would want this:

```
[[0.00,  0.49,  0.51],  
 [0.50,  0.00,  0.50],  
 [0.50,  0.50,  0.00],  
 [0.33,  0.33,  0.34],  
 [0.00,  0.00,  1.00]]
```

To really be this:

```
[[0.00,  1.00,  1.00],  
 [1.00,  0.00,  1.00],  
 [1.00,  1.00,  0.00],  
 [1.00,  1.00,  1.00],  
 [0.00,  0.00,  1.00]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use a softmax output for binary or multi class. You sigmoid and binary xent instead.

Also, this code looks a bit old. Make sure you are using 0.9.1. Don't use reconstruction cross entropy -> use  KL Divergence *if* you are doing unsupervised learning (autoencoders and the like) but for this case you shouldn't even be using recon error.

Also, the iterations knob is going away next release. Use for loops instead. That iterations knob is legacy (just leave it at 1 in the mean time)

Again, I strongly encourage you to follow our examples closer. We have everything you need in there for multi class classification or really any use case. If you can't find something try to do a keyword search in the repo. Failing that, ask on here our on our community gitter.

Comment: Hi Adam, I do not understand your reply.  I do not see binary cross entropy as an activation function, are you referring to a specif dl4j activation function name?  I have the examples, and have read through much of the gitlab, could you please point to a specific example for this classification task?     [Searching for multi class](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/search?p=2&q=multi+class&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93) for example is not helpful.  I will try out KL as the los function, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: and thanks for the heads up on iterations, I will use the for loop and yes I am using 0.9.1.

Comment: Also after using what you mentioned, SIGMOID activation on the output layer and KL divergence, I get a nonsensical answer upon convergence, basically all 1's for every training example. If you could indicate a java class from the examples repo that would be great.

Comment: You misintpreted my answer. You do *not* in any form use KL Divergence with supervised learning. I already said to use Binary XENT. Read my answer again.

Supervised learning and unsupervised learning are *very* different things. I would consider doing some reading on the terms if you're that new to things.